# Grails is interpreting a zip in my repo as a plugin, though it is not actually a plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, dependencies

A dependency of my grails project (a module that I build) outputs a zip file as part of its build process (for consumption by a flex app) using the maven-assembly-plugin. This zip is output to my local mvn repo in the same directory as the jar that is output from building the module i.e.

```
.m2/repository/com/mypackage/domain/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
.m2/repository/com/mypackage/domain/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-generated-tos.zip
```

As the module is a (transitive) dependency in my grails project, the jar and zip are both being cached in the ivy-cache

Now when I try to start my grails application, Grails seems to be detecting this zip from the ivy-cache and trying to install it as a plugin which fails for obvious reasons...

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Error Zip ~/.grails/ivy-cache/com.mypackage/domain/zips/domain-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-generated-tos.zip is not a valid plugin
```

It is necessary for the zip to be built to the repo as another module uses the mvn-dependency-plugin to unpack it as part of its build process. As such, I need to find a way of telling Grails to ignore it as it is not a plugin zip. Is this possible?

Comment: Jay, did you ever resolve this issue? I'm running into the exact same problem at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have answered this ages ago - I believe I managed to configure the maven-assembly-plugin to package the generated ActionScript files as a rar instead of a zip and this fixed the issue with Grails interpreting it as a plugin. It's been a while since I did it now so I don't have the solution to hand - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in grails the packaging of plugins is zip by default, and any archive depended upon in that format will be considered a plugin.

Try to make excludes transitive by default :

```
def excludes = {
    transitive = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing this I would assume that it was all to do with the configuration of the *BuildConfig.groovy*.

Things you put inside the dependencies block should be included as is, whereas things in the plugin block is considered a plugin zip.

I stumbled upon the problem once I misconfigured a project. The below example is not tested :)

```
dependencies {
     compile "my.project:artifact:0.1.0:zip"
}
plugins {
    compile "my.project:artifact:0.1.0" // Automatic found as a zip project
```

}